# What else can PHP create apart from websites?

Tags: php

I've been wondering. Is it possible to use php to create applications apart from just websites. If yes, whats the simplest resource?

Comment: http://gtk.php.net/docs.php | http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP can be used [from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) like you would Python or Perl.

With an extension like [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) you can add GUI functionality to applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd generally recommend other languages to do more general scripting, and especially GUI type apps, PHP *can* be used to build general purpose scripts and apps.

- more [info on shell scripting with PHP](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Shell-Scripting-With-PHP/)
- [Using PHP-GTK to build GUI apps.](http://gtk.php.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP is a general purpose scripting language but was originally designed as a server side scripting language and that shows (e.g., the `<?php` tag). Details are available on the official site http://www.php.net/docs.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do command line scripting and windowed apps (with GTK).

http://gtk.php.net/

Comment: I am on a project with php gtk2.. Was ready to give up when wanted to use GtkSheet (..unstable and didn't use) and gtkhtml(a pain to make it run). Unfortunately php gtk documentation is not  as complete as php is. However I stick with it and modified a php mvc I had for web app in order to use with gtk, it was a life saver! Also built a template class to help write pure gtk code very easily. Php gtk is not heaven.. however the power of php, the benefits of intepreted code, portability, easy db use (I use mongo), the power of cairo are there and fortunately the project is going good now.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's largest asset is probably its integration with Apache so it is 'meant' to be used for web applications. But there are other uses. For example, I use PHP through the command line ever day to administer Drupal websites, through a program called 'Drush' (Drupal Shell). You can Drush see at http://docs.drush.org/. Drush is a bash wrapper for a PHP application that bootstraps Drupal and make changes to the database, as well as interact with the file structure and CVS repository. Granted, the reason it is written in PHP is because Drupal is written in PHP, but there is no web interface. Hopefully that is a helpful real world example?

Comment: I would alter that to it's biggest asset is it's integration with SAPIs (Server APIs).  It can hook natively to many servers (not just Apache).  The SAPI is a first class citizen (unlike most other languages such as Python where it's handled by a library inside the language)...