# Is PHP-GTK being used at all today? if yes what is it being used for or can be used for?

Tags: php, linux, gtk

I dont seem to see any popular php based tutorial sites ever talking about GDK. Is it even being used? If yes what is it that can be made? the way i see it is I have the ability to build a Linux application with php which is amazing but I honestly don't see what good it can do. Maybe if someone can shine some light on it for its great use?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I dont seem to see any popular php based tutorial sites

I am afraid it has some truth in it, some very helpful link are these:

**Php Gtk Comunity page**
http://php-gtk.eu/

**Small tutorial**
http://zetcode.com/gui/phpgtktutorial/

**Sample scripts by widgets (this contains the most!)** 
http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/list-sample-codes-by-widgets/

A few other more specific link I distinguished are:

**Php+Gtk+Cairo in Particular**
http://zetcode.com/gui/phpgtktutorial/cairo/
I've done a class project on random walk (balls moving around on the screen) in cairo and it is a great library!

**Few sample scripts**
http://php-gtk.eu/en/gtk/gtkwindow

**CairoForPHP Samples**
http://fffree.phpws.org/?p=6

**PHP-GTK installer for windows (this must be very helpful!)**
http://php-gtk.eu/en/apps/php-gtk-installer-for-windows

> Is it even being used?

There are a few projects displayed on the community page. I am working my self on a class project on descision support models. 
Also I have made a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522521/642173 that is somehow relative to your question.

I wish the future will be better for php-gtk, I think it is worth.